# Scrolling Google results using Selenium WebDriver 3.4.0

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am not able to scroll Google's results page to the end. Could anyone give me pointers on the below code 1. Tried to do using JS by the following

```
(a)j.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,500)")
(b)j.executeScript("window.scrollBy(250,350)") 
(c)j.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.documentElement.scrollHeight")**

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        // Google News

        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("News");
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='rc']//a")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        JavascriptExecutor j = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
        {
            j.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,500)");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please said whats is the erro message

Comment: There are no error messages but no scrolling action is being performed upon executing the above code

Comment: @Rohit Are you trying to scroll to a specific element, or just scroll a certain way down the page?

Comment: @smit9234 I'm not trying to scroll to a specific element instead I would like to scroll down the page.

Comment: @Rohit There are multiple sections on the news results page, that is why it works on the previous page but not the news results.  Try adding another click event after you Thread.sleep, such as driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("c-wiz.fWwQIb.ChVoCd.rOrCPc.AfWyGd\n")).click();  this will tell the webdriver what section of the page to scroll.

Comment: @smit9234 Thank you for briefing.. I will check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)");
```

Scroll to particular element

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);
```

Here element is your `Webelement` from where you wanted to scroll

or you can use `Robot` class

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
```

Comment: thank you @iamsankalp89.  Using Robot class the above mentioned job is working as expected.using JS, I wonder why it is not working in google's result page alone but it works for other websites.

Answer (score 0):

Change below code

```
    for(var i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        j.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,500)");

    }
```

to

```
    for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        j.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]*500)", i);

    }
```

And it should work. 500 that you used is absolute value and not a delta for scroll. Or else use `scrollBy`

```
    for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        j.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)");

    }
```

Comment: Thank you sir for the prompt reply.

while using 

(a)j.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,500*i)"); getting the below exception
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: i is not defined
 
 (b) j.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)");
    No action is performed

Comment: change `int i` to `var i`

Comment: Thank you sir. As i am new to selenium & java couldn't resolve the below issue. "var cannot be resolved to a type" . Could you please help me this as well. Thanks for your time.

Comment: My bad, please check the edits. It should be `int` only I though the code was being executed inside JS. Now you have two version. I tested the manually in chrome on google new and they work

Comment: Thank you sir.` j.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)");` & `j.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]*500)", i);` are not performing scrolling action while execution but it works manually in other websites but not working in google news page.

Answer (score 0):

```
j.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
```

OR, you can do as follows:

```
j.executeScript("scroll(0, 250);");
```

Comment: Thank you Kapiil for the reply but no action is performed upon executing the above code. are there any other solution to this issue?

Comment: I made a typo, jse should be j as per your post.

Comment: Thank you Kapil. I had changed that to `j.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");` and `j.executeScript("scroll(0, 250);");` but still the same result

Comment: try below solution or use robot class